# How to randomize the slideshow image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have the HTML code below and want to randomize the images. How to accomplish it?

Below the code is part of html, and the code is running to show the images in order. I don't know how to ulter the javascripte and want the images can be showed randomly.

Thank you for your concern and hopefully somebody can help.
Lawrence

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/03/01/14/3DD766C300000578-4271496-image-a-39_1488378897470.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/roa.h-cdn.co/assets/16/30/1469467513-01-2016-aston-martin-db9-gt.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://article.images.consumerreports.org/prod/content/dam/CRO%20Images%202017/Magazine-Articles/April/Google-Auto-Profile-images-2017/PRF-811" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="http://www.lexus.com/byl2014/pub-share/images/series/lc.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
<br>


<script>

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a random number to choose a random image:

```
function showSlides() {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * slides.length));
        slides[rand].style.display = "block"; 
        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful!